# Тип массива для Spinner

Tags: java, android

Подскажите пожалуйста, можно для `Spinner` в ресурсах использовать не `string-array`, а `integer-array`. Последний массив как я понимаю хранит в себе примитивные данные типа `int`, и при обработке этих данных, не нужно будет приводить их к `int`?
Дело в том, что у меня описание самого `Spinner` в *xml - файле* валит приложение, если в ресурсах `String` тип массива указан как `integer-array`. Если я меняю тип массива на `string-array`, то приложение запускается.
Вот фрагмент кода из `layout`:

```
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/interval_mount"
    android:hint="@string/mount"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:entries="@array/the_number"/>
```

Вот фрагмент кода из `String`:

```
<integer-array name="the_number">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
    <item>4</item>
    <item>5</item>
    <item>6</item>
    <item>7</item>
    <item>8</item>
    <item>9</item>
    <item>10</item>
    <item>11</item>
    <item>12</item>
</integer-array>
```

Comment: Код адаптера покажите

Comment: Адаптер ещё не писался.

Comment: А с какой ошибкой валится? Возможно, компилятор пытается преобразовать ваши числа в ID строк в ресурсах, не находит их и падает. Если так, то может помочь оборачивание массива чисел в массив кастомного класса с переопределённым `toString()`

Comment: Проще всего решить этот вопрос, написав string-array с цифрами (они будут символами, а не числами). Зачем вам именно числа в спинере?

Comment: что бы избежать приведения типов.